# MongoDB database name is getting displayed after connection closing

Tags: mongodb

At method end, I have closed the connection, but it still shows the DB name -

```
public void fncConnectToMongoDB2() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        
        // Connect to the MongoDB server
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

        // Access a specific database
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("TheDB");
        System.out.println("mongo db connected");
        System.out.println(database.getName());

        //Closing the active MongoDB connection
        mongoClient.close();
        System.out.println("mongo db closed");
        System.out.println(database.getName());
    }
```

}

Output -

```
mongo db connected
TheDB
mongo db closed
TheDB
```

Comment: It will show the name because you are storing the result of mongoClient.getDatabase("TheDB") in a variable database. Once something is stored in the variable it doesn't change its value unless and until someone updates the variable. Therefore, even after closing your mongo connection, your are able to see the database name.